# Is it possible to to get parsed node through monaco editor

Tags: reactjs, parsing, html-parsing, monaco-editor

The monaco editor I use for web seems to understand where an HTML begins and ends. So it feels like it parses it. So can I use the parsing of monaco to create a nodes tree. Is it possible to do?

Ex: If I load an HTML file content in monaco editor can I use it to create a HTML node tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Monaco has no parser, just tokenizers for certain languages, which means it cannot give you a parse tree.

Comment: What about ACE Editor? Does it contains a parser?

I mean either monaco or ace - does either of them gives an AST after tokenizing the code which I can further use to create a "tree view"

Comment: You are focussing too much on the editor. Why not just build your own parsing infrastructure, like every IDE does? Listen to changes in the editor and parse the text with your own parser. This will give you the parse tree with all information.